# shiny delete tabs with action button

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny app which opens a tab once you click a marker and jumps into it. Now you could go back to the map tab and click another marker which opens another tab and so on. I want be able to remove all the opened tabs with an action button.

Below is a small example code with possibility to add and jump into a tabs once you click the markers but the action button `Remove detail tabs` is not working.

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(shinydashboard)
library(purrr)

pts <- data.frame(
  id= letters[seq( from = 1, to = 10 )],
  x = rnorm(10, mean = -93.625), 
  y = rnorm(10, mean = 42.0285)
)


ui <- fluidPage(
  dashboardSidebar(

    actionLink("remove", "Remove detail tabs")),

  tabsetPanel(id='my_tabsetPanel',
              tabPanel('Map1',
                       leafletOutput('map1')   
              )))



server <- function(input, output, session) {
  tab_list <- NULL

  output$map1 <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>% 
      addTiles() %>% 
      setView(-93.65, 42.0285, zoom = 6)
  })


  observe({        
    input$my_tabsetPanel        
    tab1 <- leafletProxy('map1', data = pts) %>%
      clearMarkers() %>% 
      addCircleMarkers(lng = ~x, lat = ~y, radius = 4, layerId = ~id)   

  })


  observeEvent(input$map1_marker_click, { 
    tab_title <- input$map1_marker_click[1]
    appendTab(inputId = "my_tabsetPanel",
              tabPanel(
                tab_title, #paste0("tab_",tab_title),
                value = paste0("tab_",tab_title),
                fluidRow(                      
                  box('test')
                )))

    tab_list <<- c(tab_list, tab_title)        
    updateTabsetPanel(session, "my_tabsetPanel", selected = paste0("tab_",tab_title))       
  })
  observeEvent(input$remove,{
    print(tab_list)
    tab_list %>%
      walk(~removeTab("my_tabsetPanel", .x))
      tab_list <<- NULL
  })

}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

---

Following makes the action button work but does not include the feature that you automatically jump into the new created tab which I would like to keep.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  dashboardSidebar(

    actionLink("remove", "Remove detail tabs")),

  tabsetPanel(id='my_tabsetPanel',
              tabPanel('Map1',
                       leafletOutput('map1')   
              )))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  tab_list <- NULL

  output$map1 <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>% 
      addTiles() %>% 
      setView(-93.65, 42.0285, zoom = 6)
  })     

  observe({        
    input$my_tabsetPanel        
    tab1 <- leafletProxy('map1', data = pts) %>%
      clearMarkers() %>% 
      addCircleMarkers(lng = ~x, lat = ~y, radius = 4, layerId = ~id)        

  })


  observeEvent(input$map1_marker_click, { 
    tab_title <- input$map1_marker_click[1]
    appendTab(inputId = "my_tabsetPanel",
              tabPanel(
                tab_title, 
                fluidRow(                      
                  box('test')                      
                )))        
    tab_list <<- c(tab_list, tab_title)        
    updateTabsetPanel(session, "my_tabsetPanel", selected = tab_title) 

  })
  observeEvent(input$remove,{
    print(tab_list)
    tab_list %>%
      walk(~removeTab("my_tabsetPanel", .x))

    tab_list <<- NULL
  })

}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I struggle to combine both versions into one that works.

Example [link](https://edgarruiz.shinyapps.io/flights-dashboard/) where everything works as it should.

Comment: Are you talking about the working example link? Yes there its working but not in my example

Comment: Oh, oops. I didn't register that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright I actually found a way. You need to use a `paste()` around  the tab title name element. Why? I have no idea.

Following server part combined with the UI from above works then

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  tab_list <- NULL

  output$map1 <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>% 
      addTiles() %>% 
      setView(-93.65, 42.0285, zoom = 6)
  })


  observe({        
    input$my_tabsetPanel        
    tab1 <- leafletProxy('map1', data = pts) %>%
      clearMarkers() %>% 
      addCircleMarkers(lng = ~x, lat = ~y, radius = 4, layerId = ~id)   

  })


  observeEvent(input$map1_marker_click, { 
    clickedMarker <- input$map1_marker_click[1]
    tab_title <- paste(clickedMarker) #add paste() here and it works      

    appendTab(inputId = "my_tabsetPanel",
              tabPanel(
                tab_title,
                fluidRow(                      
                  box('test')
                )))

    tab_list <<- c(tab_list, tab_title) 


    updateTabsetPanel(session, "my_tabsetPanel", selected = tab_title)       
  })


  observeEvent(input$remove,{
    print(tab_list)
    tab_list %>%
      walk(~removeTab("my_tabsetPanel", .x))
    tab_list <<- NULL
  })

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so removeUI() function with option multiple = TRUE will remove all list elements except first (in this case Map tab itself).

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(shinydashboard)
library(purrr)

pts <- data.frame(
  id= letters[seq( from = 1, to = 10 )],
  x = rnorm(10, mean = -93.625), 
  y = rnorm(10, mean = 42.0285)
)


ui <- fluidPage(
  dashboardSidebar(

    actionLink("remove", "Remove detail tabs")),

  tabsetPanel(id='my_tabsetPanel',
              tabPanel('Map1',
                       leafletOutput('map1')   
              )))



server <- function(input, output, session) {
  tab_list <- NULL

  output$map1 <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>% 
      addTiles() %>% 
      setView(-93.65, 42.0285, zoom = 6)
  })


  observe({        
    input$my_tabsetPanel        
    tab1 <- leafletProxy('map1', data = pts) %>%
      clearMarkers() %>% 
      addCircleMarkers(lng = ~x, lat = ~y, radius = 4, layerId = ~id)   

  })


  observeEvent(input$map1_marker_click, { 
    tab_title <- input$map1_marker_click[1]
    appendTab(inputId = "my_tabsetPanel",
              tabPanel(
                tab_title, #paste0("tab_",tab_title),
                value = paste0("tab_",tab_title),
                fluidRow(                      
                  box('test')
                )))

    tab_list <<- c(tab_list, tab_title)        
    updateTabsetPanel(session, "my_tabsetPanel", selected = paste0("tab_",tab_title))       
  })
  observeEvent(input$remove,{
    removeUI(
      selector = "ul>li:nth-child(n+2)",
      multiple = TRUE
    )
    removeUI(
      selector = "div.box-body",
      multiple = TRUE
    )
  })

}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: No idea, but removeUI() is easy and effective solution so why not to use it:)

Comment: oh just saw once you open multiple tabs they don't get deleted at once

Comment: I believe the functionality of removeUI() it removes one single element at a time on button click.

Comment: yeah that works kind of but I look for something like in the working example link where you can delete all tabs at once in one click

Comment: @CER I updated code. In order to remove multiple elements, you should use multiple = TRUE in removeUI() function.

Comment: its actually simple, just add an `updateTabsetPanel(session, "my_tabsetPanel", selected = 'Map1') ` after the last `removeUI` part

Comment: Just realized that `removeUI` removes the `box` element for good. Means when you click the action bution, remove the tab and reopen it the `box` element is not showing anymore. From the doc > Once removeUI is executed on some element, it is gone forever.